# How to fix high valence vertex?

Tags: mesh, topology

I discovered a vertex on my mesh with 6 edges connected to it. It is causing problems with smoothing. How do I solve this problem without deforming the mesh?[image]

[image]

Comment: The vertex with 6 edges shouldn’t be a problem in itself - more likely the problem is the two very non-planar quads just below it, and possibly the one immediately to the right.